# Number of possible n-towers

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, recursion

This question is inspired by Q5 from the 2018 MAT, but it is *not* the same.

> An $n$-brick is defined as a rectangle with height $1$ and width $n$. A $1$-tower is defined as a $1$-brick.
> An $n$-tower for $n$ greater than or equal to two is an $n$-brick atop which any number of towers are stacked. The $n$-bricks directly above the first one should sum to $n$ (so if you had a $4$-tower, you could put a $3$-brick and a $1$-brick on it, or two $2$-bricks on it. The $3$-brick would then have either three $1$-bricks on it, or one $2$-brick and one $1$-brick; whereas the $2$-brick would always have two $1$-bricks).  Below is a picture of a $4$-tower

[image: A 4-tower]

> If $s_n$ is the number of *n*-towers, can you write $s_n$ in terms of $s_k$ where $k<n$?

Comment: what is $s_k$ in this question?

Comment: What have you tried? @justaguy The number of $k-$towers.

Comment: @Phicar maybe i'm not understanding right but from my understanding there is no relation between the two.

Comment: @justaguy Why not? notice that in the $4$ tower the OP placed $3-$tower and $1-$tower, but the OP could have put $2$ and $2$ and whatever in top of them. So there is a relation in between $s_n$ and $s_k$ mainly a recursion.

Comment: @Phicar but they also could have placed n 1-bricks. So there is no definite relation between them

Comment: @justaguy I understand that the OP means over all possible $k'$s. In other words a recursion.(I put the recursion before, but i prefer to see the OP attempt, sorry for the inconvenience).

Answer (score 2):

Your $n$-towers are Schröder trees in disguise — plane trees with $n$ leaves, all of whose internal nodes have at least two children. Each brick is a node, each $1$-brick is a leaf, and each $k$-brick for $k\ge 2$ is an internal node. These are enumerated by the [Schröder-Hipparchus numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Hipparchus_number), also known as *little Schröder* or *super-Catalan* numbers; [OEIS A001003](https://oeis.org/A001003) has a lot of information and references. It also has two fairly nice recurrences. One is similar to the familiar Catalan recurrence:

$$s_{n+1}=-s_n+2\sum_{k=1}^ns_ks_{n+1-k}$$

For instance,

$$\begin{align*}
s_5&=-s_4+2\sum_{k=1}^4s_ks_{5-k}\\
&=-11+2(1\cdot11+1\cdot3+3\cdot1+11\cdot1)\\
&=45\;.
\end{align*}$$

The other is second-order:

$$ns_n=3(2n-3)s_{n-1}-(n-3)s_{n-2}$$

E.g., $5s_5=24s_4-2s_3=21\cdot11-2\cdot3=225$, so $s_5=\frac{225}5=45$. Foata and Zeilberger have a nice combinatorial proof of this recurrence [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9805015.pdf) [PDF].